# what is the meaning of 'population' and 'sample' in statistics

Tags: statistics

In the context of finding the average weight of crows, the [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_%28statistics%29) article  mentions that the 'population' is the set of measurements of weights. However, the same wiki article also uses 'population' to refer to the set of crows (rather then the weights), and this is how I see the term 'population' used in most statistics resources.

Also, informally, the term 'sample' is usually used to indicate a subset, for example some of the crows, but when I read more formal introduction to statistics, the definition of random sample is usually defined to be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables.

So here is my question:

If I consider $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ to be a random sample, where all $X_i$s have the same distribution as $X$, then what is the 'population' in this context? Is it $X$, is it the domain of $X$ or is it something else? Or is this a meaningful question at all?

Comment: Not quite, the article could have been phrased differently. The population is all the crows. The population **weights** are the weights of all crows. The sample is the $n$ crows you take from the population. The sample **weights** are the weights of the crows in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

You never defined what X is. If your sample is drawn from a set called X, then X is the population.

A population is a set. A sample is a subset of a population. Nobody cares about samples within samples and other insanity because those are nonproblems.